# Separating contents of different types stored in a list using python

Tags: python

I have a list containing oscar nominees in the following format.

```
Birdman 2014    4   9    
The Grand Budapest Hotel    2014    4   9   
Whiplash    2014    3   5
```

What I am trying to do is separate them in different categories: `Movie`, `Year`, `oscars`, `nominations`.

I cant separate them using the empty space because there are spaces within the movie titles. Any ideas on how I could do this please.

Comment: Use regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Post the code that you used.

Comment: You may want to look into tab separated format for your input.

Comment: split them by spaces and move backwards.

Comment: @JanSpurny, thanks for the laugh. "Now you have two problems" comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a try with this:

```
#I assume the data is in 'text' as a string.
data = text.split()
Movie, Year, oscars, nominations = ''.join(data[:-3]), data[-3], data[-2], data[-1]
```

---

So, considering the data is in a list, this could be loaded in a for loop:

```
# list_of_lines is a list where each item is a line of data
whole_data = list()
for text in line_of_lines:
    data = text.split()
    whole_data.append({'title':''.join(data[:-3]), 'year': data[-3], 'oscars': data[-2], 'nominations': data[-1]})
    # Do something with your info
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way. +1

Comment: tglaria, I would add a bit of code since this handles the input data line by line. Perhaps add a `for` block to go through every line in `data` and store the results in a dictionary.

Comment: thank you, this is perfect. I was trying to split them but couldnt figure out how. , this works very well, thank you.

Comment: @Gabriel I thought about it, but was looking for the most compact way. Let's update the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a dictionary in python.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

```
dict_var = {'title': 'Birdman', 'releasedate': 2014};
```

And accessing them:

```
dict_var['title'] == 'Birdman'
dict_var['releasedate'] == 2014
```

Comment: hi, yea i was thinking of a dictionary but there is 1100 different movies so it would take alot of work.

Comment: Fair enough. In scripting languages like Python, if you have large sets of data like that it can often be a good idea to iterate over all of them (in a way that doesn't require you going through each one by one) and store them in an accessible manner. But there are many solutions, so I'm glad you found one!

As a side note, you can use a for loop to iterate over each item in a collection so that you don't have to do things one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split movie entry into those four fields doing this:

```
str = "The Grand Budapest Hotel    2014    4   9   "
tmp = str.split()
[" ".join(tmp[0:len(tmp)-3])] + tmp[len(tmp)-3:len(tmp)]
```

Comment: hi, there were 1100 movies in the list so there would have been too much work doing each movie individually, but thanks for the reply

Comment: Just use loop then. This is an example for single entry on that list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you exploit the fact that the only unit of information that includes the ambiguous spaces is the title? For example:

```
a = 'Birdman 2014 4 9'
b = 'The Grand Budapest Hotel 2014 4 9'
```

If we use `split` to break these up into words:

```
>>> aa.split()
['Birdman', '2014', '4', '9']
>>> bb.split()
['The', 'Grand', 'Budapest', 'Hotel', '2014', '4', '9']
```

We get lists of different counts (4 and 7 respectively). BUT we know that the `nominations` will always be last and only the last word. Python's reverse indexing is very nice here.

```
>>> aa = a.split()
>>> bb = b.split()
>>> aa[-1]
'9'
>>> bb[-1]
'9'
```

We can index the `oscars` and `year` as well:

```
>>> aa[-2] # oscars
'4'
>>> bb[-2] # oscars
'4'
>>> aa[-3] # year
'2014'
>>> bb[-3] # year
'2014'
```

Use the `int()` function if you need to turn these words back into numbers. To get the title, we can access a slice of the list, using that same reverse indexing.

```
>>> aa[0:-3] # title
['Birdman']
>>> bb[0:-3] # title
['The', 'Grand', 'Budapest', 'Hotel']
```

Note that the `[0:-3]` can simply be written as `[:-3]`, 0 is the default value for the start index expressed to the left of the `:` character.

Lists of one or more words are probably not the way you want to express your titles, so to turn them back into a single string, use the `join()` method:

```
>>> awords = aa[:-3]
>>> aWords = aa[:-3]
>>> bWords = bb[:-3]
>>> ' '.join(aWords)
'Birdman'
>>> ' '.join(bWords)
'The Grand Budapest Hotel'
```

If you're going to do it a lot, I'd write a simple parser that turned your single line string into something more structured. Let's use a simple object with named fields:

```
class MovieRecord(object):
    pass
```

(You could use a named tuple as well, or a dictionary, but I think that classes are always nice, because as my program grows, I can bind behavior to the object data that is a natural fit for it, the other options are a flatter more static approach and tend to lead to behavior not well encapsulated throughout your program).

Now we need a function to parse a single text line into a MovieRecord. Taking what we established above:

```
def parseMovie(line):
    newRecord = MovieRecord()
    words = line.split()
    newRecord.name = ' '.join(words[:-3])
    newRecord.year = int(words[-3])
    newRecord.oscars = int(words[-2])
    newRecord.nominations = int(words[-1])
    return newRecord
```

Testing that out:

```
>>> sample = 'The Grand Budapest Hotel 2014 4 9'
>>> record = parseMovie(sample)
>>> record.name
'The Grand Budapest Hotel'
>>> record.year
2014
>>> record.oscars
4
>>> record.nominations
9
```

Not much left now. Given a file of those lines, we can leverage the fact that python likes to read files lines at a time by default:

```
with open('yourListOfMovies', 'r') as file:
    allMovies = [parseMovie(line) for line in file]
```